# Excel VBA - Insert a row below, copy the formulas and formats and insert specific default data in select columns

Tags: excel, vba, insert, row, formula

I have a considerable database in Excel. About half of the column data are entered by hand. One problem has plagued me for some time.
I insert rows by hand.
I copy the formulae by hand. Quite Error prone.
I set up the formats by hand.
The sheet is fairly complex.

I've tried to automate the process, alas always with some bug or another.

```
Sub InsertRow()
ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrAbove
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

This doesn't seem to copy the formulae. And how would I put default values in the specific columns?

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution for your problem. Install the code in the code module of the worksheet on which you wish to insert rows. It's one of the pre-existing modules in the workbook, named after the tab. If you want the same action on several worksheets install a version of the procedure in each applicable code module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Const TriggerClm    As String = "A"     ' change to suit
    Const FirstDataRow  As Long = 2         ' change to suit
    Dim Rng             As Range
    
    Set Rng = Cells(Rows.Count, TriggerClm).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    With Target
        If (.Address = Rng.Address) And (.Row > FirstDataRow) Then
            Rows(.Row - 1).Copy             ' copies from last used row
'            Rows(FirstDataRow).Copy         ' copies from FirstDataRow
            Rows(.Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            On Error Resume Next
            Rows(.Row - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

And this is what will happen. The code module captures when you double-click on a cell and the above procedure responds to that action. If the double-click was on the blank cell below the last used cell in column A (TriggerClm) a blank row will be inserted at that point. It will contain all the formats and formulas it copies from either the row above or the first row in the sheet (FirstDataRow).

And that also defines the required setup. You can specify a TriggerClm other that "A" and a FirstDataRow other than 2. And you must chose between the two sources to copy from, disabling the one you don't want to use. Please read the remarks in the code.

After many years of wavering I now favour the last used row over the first in most of my projects. I also usually add code to insert the date if one is required, usually in the TriggerClm.

You may be familiar with the original function of double-click to switch to in-cell editing. This functionality is cancelled when a row is inserted. But if you take out `Cancel = True` then the code would stop in Edit mode in the new cell.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code if you want to leave it as a macro in a module. Not that when excel copies "formulas" it also copies values. I also added a lien to show you how to change column 3 to 5

```
Sub InsertRow()

Dim CurRow As Range
Dim NewRow As Range

ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
Set CurRow = ActiveCell.EntireRow.Offset(1)
Set NewRow = ActiveCell.EntireRow
CurRow.Copy
NewRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
NewRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False
NewRow.Columns(3) = 5
End Sub
```